# Powershell - Outlook - add multiple attachments to email

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, attachment

I want to add more than one attachment to an e-mail.
With one no problem but if you are trying to add two or more something goes wrong

My code

```
$file_patch=Get-ChildItem 'C:\OUTLOOK' | Sort {$_.LastWriteTime} | select -last 1 | % { $_.FullName }
$name=Select-String -Path $file_patch -pattern name
$email=Select-String -Path $file_patch -pattern email
$subject=Select-String -Path $file_patch -pattern subject
$attachment=Select-String -Path $file_patch -pattern attachment
$Signature = Get-Content ($env:USERPROFILE + "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\*.htm")
$rname = $name -replace ".*:"
$remail = $email -replace ".*:"
$rsubject = $subject -replace ".*:"
$rattachment = $attachment -replace ".*attachment:"
$sname = $rname -split ";"
$semail = $remail -split ";"
$ssubject = $rsubject -split ";"
$sattachment = $rattachment -split ";"
$body=Get-Content C:\OUTLOOK\BODY\$sname.txt
$Signature = Get-Content ($env:USERPROFILE + "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\*.htm")
$sRecipientAddr = $semail
$sMsgSubject = $ssubject
$oOutlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application 
$oMapiNs = $oOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$oMailMsg = $oOutlook.CreateItem(0)
$oMailMsg.GetInspector.Activate()
$sSignature = $oMailMsg.HTMLBody
[Void]$oMailMsg.Recipients.Add($sRecipientAddr)
$oMailMsg.Attachments.Add($sattachment)
$oMailMsg.Subject = $sMsgSubject
$oMailMsg.HTMLBody = $body + $sSignature
```

My file

name:Outlook
email:e-mail@lest.pl;boss@company.com;random.dude@email.com
Subject:You are great
attachment:"C:\outlook\attachment\sell.txt";"C:\outlook\attachment\out.txt"

Error :

```
PS > Value does not fall within the expected range.
+ $oMailMsg.Attachments.Add($sattachment)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : OperationStopped: (:) [], A
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

What could be wrong

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to pass an array directly into `.attachments.add()`. The [page here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553.aspx) has the usage of the `Add` method.

Therefore, I think if you add the attachments in a slightly different way you should succeed:

```
...
$sSignature = $oMailMsg.HTMLBody
[Void]$oMailMsg.Recipients.Add($sRecipientAddr)
$sattachment | ForEach-Object { $oMailMsg.Attachments.Add($_) }
$oMailMsg.Subject = $sMsgSubject
$oMailMsg.HTMLBody = $body + $sSignature
```

Assuming `$sattachment = $rattachment -split ";"` does actually return an array of strings, you can loop over it using the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet. The `.Add()` method will then be called for each array element, which is represented by `$_` within the block.